# .Net web service client takes long time to fail on call when server web service is down

Tags: java, .net, web-services

I have a .Net web service client that consumes a Java web service.  When the Java app server is down the client takes a long time to throw an exception.  I have redundant systems in place but for the best customer experience I need to know that the service is down quickly so I can fail over as fast as possible.

Is there a setting on the client to make it time out faster when the service is down?

The java service is a SOAP service running on JBoss.

The client is a .Net 3.5 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config file there should be a bindings section.
You will see something like this :

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
```

I believe these are the nodes you are looking for(*add star wars hand motion)

Comment: So openTimeout is probably the droid I'm looking for.  Thanks!